# Error starting Ubuntu 16.04 LTS: Read-only file system

Tags: 16.04, grub2, login

A couple of weeks ago I installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on my laptop and everything was okay until a few days ago. When I turned it on the GRUB menu appeared, I selected "Ubuntu" (which is the only operating system I have on the laptop) and I see this:

```
[   2.885318] usb 1-1.4: string descriptor 0 read error: -22
/dev/sda1: clean, 280041/30212096 files, 4757902/120888400 blocks
[   15.638930] usb 1-1.4: string descriptor 0 read error: -22
```

The laptop stays for about 3 minutes in that message and then appears **Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS tty1**. I login with my username and password and I automatically see this message:

```
/usr/lib/ubuntu-release-upgrader/release-upgrade-motd: 31: /usr/lib/ubuntu-release-upgrader/release-upgrade-motd: cannot create /var/lib/ubuntu-release-upgrader/ release-upgrade-available: Read-only file system

/usr/lib/update-notifier/update-motd-fsck-at-reboot: 33: /usr/lib/update-notifier/update-motd-fsck-at-reboot: cannot create /var/lib/update-notifier/fsck-at-reboot: Read-only file system
cat: /var/lib/update-notifier/fsck-at-reboot: No such file or directory


run-parts: /etc/update-motd.d/98-fsck-at-reboot exited with return code 1
```

What should I do there?

Sorry for my English

Answer (score 2):

Lets first unplug all USB devices, and then check your file system for errors.

To check the file system on your Ubuntu partition...

- boot to the GRUB menu
- choose Advanced Options
- choose Recovery mode
- choose Root access
- at the # prompt, type `sudo fsck -f /`
- repeat the fsck command if there were errors
- type `reboot`

If for some reason you can't do the above...

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB
- start `gparted` and determine which /dev/sdaX is your Ubuntu EXT4 partition
- quit `gparted`
- open a `terminal` window
- type `sudo fsck -f /dev/sdaX` # replacing X with the number you found earlier
- repeat the fsck command if there were errors
- type `reboot`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Start with a live-cd / usb.

After charging, open a terminal.

At the terminal log in as root.

```
sudo -i
```

Find out what your linux partitions are called.

```
fdisk -l
```

Suppose they are /dev/sda1 for / root and /dev/sda3 for / home.
Execute then

```
umount /dev/sda1
fsck -a /dev/sda1
umount /dev/sda3
fsck -a /dev/sda3
```

Restart your computer

```
reboot
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using something like a Raspberry Pi and not able to get into Grub, create a 2nd boot SD card. Boot with the working SD, connect a USB SD adapter containing the malfunctioning SD card.

Then run:

```
sudo fsck -f <on the SD in the adapter, likely /dev/sda1>
```

Once the first partition on the SD card is fixed you can 'sudo shutdown now' on the unit, and boot with the once malfunctioning SD card. It should boot now.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue with **Lubuntu 18.04** (**64 bits**) and I used `fsck` on the installation hard drive as suggested in the top answers. However, that did not remove the error when logging into my account (*it did solve some issues with the partition though*).

I looked at the logs Ubuntu writes at boot and noticed that several services that required the `mount` command failed to execute. I then booted a **Live session** of the same OS (*same architecture, 64 bits*) and noticed that the `/bin` folder of the affected system was missing several important binaries such as `mount`, `ls`, `nano`, etc.

I decided to copy the contents of the **Live session** `/bin` folder into the affected system `/bin` folder without replacing files (*just copying what wasn't there*) and when I booted the affected system there were no errors and it started normally.

My computer was shut down because of a **power outage** so I assume some weird error happened that let to the loss of those files in the system.

I know it is an old question but in case someone else has this issue I would recommend **checking missing files among the folders of the affected system** and with a **Live session of the same OS replace the pertinent files to see if the system can be recovered**.

Similar issue I found --> https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/after-taking-power-out-of-raspberry-pi-ubuntu-wont-boot-correctly/20825

Comment: None of this answer has anything to do with what the OP asked.